# Why does this MYSQL UPDATE query take 2 minutes to run?

Tags: mysql, sql

This query takes almost 2 minutes to execute (changing 9 records):

```
UPDATE table1 t1
SET t1.code_id = null, t1.code_group = null
WHERE t1.another_id IN (SELECT t2.another_id 
                        FROM table2 t2
                        WHERE ((t2.id_parent = 2658 AND t2.year = 2016) 
                               OR (t2.id = 2658 AND t2.year = 2016)))
```

Executing this query alone takes 0.0030s:

```
SELECT t2.another_id 
FROM table2 t2
WHERE ((t2.id_parent = 2658 AND t2.year = 2016) 
       OR (t2.id = 2658 AND t2.year = 2016))
```

and returns 3 rows in form of a integer.

Here is info about both tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1` 
(
  `another_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `table1_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `code_group` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `code_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`another_id`,`table1_id`),
  KEY `another_id` (`another_id`),
  KEY `code_group` (`code_group`,`code_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table2` 
(
  `id_year` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_parent` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `another_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `code_group` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `code_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_year`,`id`),
  KEY `id_parent` (`id_year`,`id_parent`)
  KEY `another_id` (`another_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_polish_ci;
```

Is there anyone, who can tell my why it needs 2 minutes to execute this query?

Comment: why ((t2.id_parent= 2658 AND t2.year= 2016) two times in or?

Comment: use Explain to see where you Need an index

Comment: From my experience MySQL sometimes seems to have problems optimizing unrelated subqueries, so that they seem to get executed for each row again. In your case I would suggest run the subselect in a separate query and then create the actual query with just the results dynamically in your application.

Comment: Try to use Index for optimize it. CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX...

Comment: `table2` does not have a column `t2.another_id`. MySQL will join over it, so it is relevant which column it is.

Comment: I deleted too much from original code. There is, of course, column t2.another_id. Thanks for finding this error. I have updated my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use INNER JOIN to update as following:t2.year is also not exist

```
UPDATE table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.another_id = t1.another_id
    AND ((t2.id_parent= 2658 AND t2.year= 2016) OR (t2.id= 2658 AND t2.year= 2016))
SET t1.code_id = NULL, t1.code_group = NULL
```

Comment: Hey, I am unable to execute this query. MySQL returns sytax error at line 2.

Comment: I have updated the query according to MYSQL BTW I am not getting year column in T2.

Answer (score 1):

`IN` can sometimes impede optimization.  I would start by putting the subquery directly in the `FROM` clause:

```
UPDATE table1 t1 JOIN
       (SELECT t2.another_id 
        FROM table2 t2
        WHERE ((t2.id_parent= 2658 AND t2.year= 2016) OR
               (t2.id= 2658 AND t2.year= 2016)
              )
       ) t2
       ON t1.another_id = t2.another_id
    SET t1.code_id = null,
        t1.code_group = null;
```

Then, looking at this query, I would recommend an index on `table1(another_id)`.  In fact, that index might be sufficient for your original query.

Comment: While I still cannot find reasonable answer for main question (there was already index for "another_id" on both tables) , your solution works like a charm. Turning 2 minutes query into 0.0040s one.

Thanks;)

Comment: @JacMar . . . The answer to your question is that `IN` sometimes impedes optimization.